# VB6 Join on LongArray gives Type mismatch error after windows update

Tags: vb6

As of a windows update, the Join operator in VB6 is throwing a Type mismatch error.

My vb6 jtTaskBO class has the following properties;

```
Friend Property Set PredecessorOffsets(ByVal Offsets As LongArray)
    mPredecessorOffsets.Assign Offsets
End Property

Public Property Get PredecessorOffsets() As LongArray
    Set PredecessorOffsets = mPredecessorOffsets
End Property
```

My code has been working for years but I had to modify it today as follows;

```
Private Function GetPredecessorsDisplay(bo As jtTaskBO)
    On Error GoTo error_handle:
    ' This used to work
    ' GetPredecessorsDisplay =  Join(bo.PredecessorOffsets, ", ")
    ' replaced by the following
    Dim s As String
    s = ""

    If Not IsNull(bo.PredecessorOffsets) Then
      If (bo.PredecessorOffsets.Count > 0) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim n As Integer
        n = bo.PredecessorOffsets.Count - 1
        For i = 0 To n
            If i <> 0 Then s = s & ", "
            s = s & bo.PredecessorOffsets(i)
        Next
      End If
    End If
    GetPredecessorsDisplay = s
exit_point:
    Exit Function
error_handle:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume exit_point
End Function
```

Winver reports

```
Windows 10 version 1809 Build 17763.678
```

A user also reports the issue with Windows 7

Is there any way to fix the issue without doing a release?

I see there is mention of VB6 in [KB4511553](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4511553/windows-10-update-kb4511553) or [KB4512508](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4512508/windows-10-update-kb4512508)

[Update]

I updated to version 1903 Build 18362.295 but the issue is still there.

Is there an official channel to report to Microsoft via?

Comment: If it's related to this, you could wait a fix from Microsoft. https://www.reddit.com/r/visualbasic/comments/cq8kkn/weird_error_after_august_2019_patch_day/

Comment: Are you sure the VB6 tag is the right tag? `LongArray` isn't a recognizable data type in my VB6. Could it be that it's VBA?

Comment: @Kaniu  Thank you. I am also experiencing the param array issue.

Comment: As Hel O'Ween already said, LongArray is not a native VB6 data type. I guess, there is an external reference to some kind of library which is broken by the windows update. To check this you can open the VBP file with a text editor. Then look for all lines which begin with "Reference=" or "Object=" and verify if the referenced files really exist. Good luck! :)